# dont want to show the fileds that not have values in database

Tags: php, input

I have multiple fields in a form that are storing data to database. on the front i have write the `HTML` for all the fields but i only want to show those fields that have value in database.

```
<?php if ($result['condition_en'] && ($result['condition_en'] != "Null")) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td width="19%" align="right" valign="middle" class="tdL">Condition</td>
        <td width="81%"><?php echo $result['condition_en']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($result['construction_en'] && ($result['construction_en'] != "Null")) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="middle" class="tdL" >Construction:</td>
        <td><?php echo $result['construction_en']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

**I have tried it in this way but nothing works any solution?**

Comment: Are you sure that `$result['construction_en']` equals `"Null"` which is a string and not real `NULL` value?

Comment: Well, you are comparing with a string "Null" not actual `NULL`, remove the quotes around Null

Comment: What is the meaning of using this: $result['condition_en'] != "Null"

Comment: Checking `$result['condition_en']` value matches with string 'Null'

Comment: Select record in which have value.. from database

Comment: If you want to make use all value from database than 
check column 
!empty($result['column'])

Comment: basic need it to check and compare if the field value is empty then not show it on front end.

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers. @shoaib-fareed

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
<?php 
if(!empty($result['condition_en']))
{ 
?>
    <tr>
        <td width="19%" align="right" valign="middle" class="tdL">Condition</td>
        <td width="81%"><?php echo $result['condition_en']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php 
} 
?>
<?php 
if(!empty($result['construction_en'])) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="middle" class="tdL" >Construction:</td>
        <td><?php echo $result['construction_en']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php 
} 
?>
```

Comment: but i told you there is a big difference between string "Null" and DB NULL

Answer (score 0):

Use Like:

```
<?php if (!empty($result['condition_en']) && isset($result['condition_en']) && $result['condition_en'] != NULL && $result['condition_en'] != "") { ?>
<tr>
<td width="19%" align="right" valign="middle" class="tdL">Condition</td>
<td width="81%"><?php echo $result['condition_en']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: If variable is not **empty** - it's definitely **set**

Comment: No reason to be ussing `isset()` when you are using `empty()`

Comment: If variable is not **empty** - it definitely not equals `''`. All these checks are redundant.

Comment: There is no "safe side" it's completely bloat code.

Answer (score 0):

Change your checking from

```
if ($result['condition_en'] && $result['condition_en'] != "Null")
```

To

```
if ($result['condition_en'] && $result['condition_en'] != "")
```

Because you are currently checking for the `"Null"` string rather than the `NULL` value itself. Better to check if the value is empty.

Comment: he can use !empty($result['condition_en'])

Comment: I have used this condition now and its hide both the section that is empty and also the other one that has value:
      
           <?php if ($result['construction_en'] && (!empty($result['condition_en']))) { ?>

Comment: in this scene it is not hiding any one either it is empty or not:
 <?php if ($result['construction_en'] && ($result['construction_en'] != "")) { ?>

@ William Madede

Comment: Okay...im going to sort you out...how does your while-loop looks like after you do a select? please post it here...done

Comment: i am not using while loop. i have fetched the contents on ID Based.
$query = "select * from  table_name where id='" . $id . "'";

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98718/discussion-between-shoaib-fareed-and-william-madede).